# How to give focus to emacsclient window when opening org-protocol?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have `(require 'org-protocol)` in .emacs.
Now with in bash:

```
emacsclient org-protocol://capture://something
```

I get what I want, except emacs window is not focused.
To make it focused, I could, for instance give a `-c` flag to `emacsclient`.
Is there a way(maybe an `-e` switch) to do this without `-c`?

Answer (score 2):

Found this code to fix it:

```
(defadvice raise-frame (after make-it-work (&optional frame) activate)
    "Work around some bug? in raise-frame/Emacs/GTK/Metacity/something.
     Katsumi Yamaoka posted this in 
     http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel:39702"
     (call-process
     "wmctrl" nil nil nil "-s" "1")
     (call-process
     "wmctrl" nil nil nil "-i" "-R"
     (frame-parameter (or frame (selected-frame)) 'outer-window-id)))
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook 'raise-frame)
```

Apparenty `raise-frame` is still bugged, so `wmctrl` is used instead.

Comment: This breaks my org 7.9.2 capture with greedy handler errors. On the other hand, it looks like the frame is automatically raised (emacs24, xubuntu)

Comment: @abo-abo, you say you "found this code". Where, and under what license? Credit where credit is due, please.